# Unwanted quotes appearing in data while saving dataframe as file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I first read a delimited file with multiple rows and index rows using zip with index.
Next I'm trying to write that dataframe which is created from a RDD[Row] to a csv file using scala.

This is my code :

```
val FileDF = spark.read.csv(inputfilepath)

val rdd = FileDF.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(indexedRow => Row.fromSeq((indexedRow._2.toLong+SEED+1) +: indexedRow._1.toSeq))

val FileDFWithSeqNo = StructType(Array(StructField("UniqueRowIdentifier",LongType)).++(FileDF.schema.fields))

val dataframenew = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,FileDFWithSeqNo)

dataframenew.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").save("C:\\Users\\path\\Desktop\\IndexedOutput")
```

where dataframenew is the final dataframe.

Input data is like :

```
0|0001|10|1|6001825851|0|0|0000|0|003800543||2017-03-02 00:00:00|95|O|473|3.74|0.05|N|||5676|6001661630||473|1|||UPS|2017-03-02 00:00:00|0.0000||0||20170303|793358|793358115230979
0|0001|10|1|6001825853|0|0|0000|0|003811455||2017-03-02 00:00:00|95|O|90|15.14|0.55|N|||1080|6001661630||90|1|||UPS|2017-03-02 00:00:00|0.0000||0||20170303|793358|793358115230980
0|0001|10|1|6001825854|0|0|0000|0|003812898||2017-03-02 00:00:00|95|O|15|7.60|1.33|N|||720|6001661630||15|1|||UPS|2017-03-02 00:00:00|0.0000||0||20170303|793358|793358115230981
```

I'm zipping with index to get unique identifier for each row.

But this gives me an output file with data like :

```
1001,"0|0001|10|1|6001825851|0|0|0000|PS|0|0.0000||0||20170303|793358|793358115230979",cabc
```

While the expected output should be :

```
1001,0|0001|10|1|6001825851|0|0|0000|PS|0|0.0000||0||20170303|793358|793358115230979,cabc
```

Why are the extra quotes getting added into the data and how can I eliminate this?

Comment: @RohanOswal, add the same `option("delimiter", "|")` while reading the file and your problem is solved. `Explanation to the problemn you had` : there was `|` in the data you read and when the same delimiter is used for output, spark made the string you read safe as one string and thats why " was appended to the whole string.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thanks this works perfect. But does this take more processing time as data is divided into multiple columns based on delimiter? As the earlier approach read all data into a single column according to my assumption.

Comment: @RohanOswal, the time taken would be negligible. And I am happy that it helped. :)